# Matlab object getting XData and YData from an axis object handle

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I can't even describe a problem well because of my ignorance in this subject.  Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a figure with bunch of objects on it such as text, line that contains the data being plotted, and groups created by imline.

Now, I have to perform an analysis with Xdata and YData from the axis.  So, I'm doing this:

```
axis_h = findobj(gcf,'Type','axes');
```

Then, I do the following:

```
obj_h = get(axis_h,'Children');
```

So, I get the following:

```
3x1 graphics array:

Text     (\DeltaY/\DeltaX = 27719.3352    [\DeltaX = 0.01788,  \DeltaY = 495.62…)
Group    (imline)
Line     (Fp\_ext vs. Xp\_UPR (ez5 rud revJ.dyn stiff singlePCU nom OR dmp 0p01…)
```

Now I need to get XData and YData from Line graphic array and I don't know how.

I tried the following:

```
line   = findobj(obj_h,'Type','line');
```

So, I get the following:

```
5x1 graphics array:

Line    (Fp\_ext vs. Xp\_UPR (ez5 rud revJ.dyn stiff singlePCU nom OR dmp 0p018…)
Line    (end point 2)
Line    (end point 1)
Line    (top line)
Line    (bottom line)
```

The same problem, I don't know how to get XData and YData from the first line object only.

I don't want to do obj_h(3) or line(1) to get XDat and YData because I don't think it's robust.

What is the robust way of getting XData and YData from "Line     (Fp_ext vs. Xp_UPR (ez5 rud revJ.dyn stiff singlePCU nom OR dmp 0p01…)"?

Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you,

Eric

Comment: I think you're going a little too deep. You should just be able to get the xdata as `xd = get(axis_h, 'XData')`.

Comment: "_I don't want to do_ `line(1).XData` _and_ `YData` _because I don't think it's robust._" ... and yet this is the way to do it ... what do you mean by _It's not robust_ ?